# How can I do natural sort in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, datetime, sql-order-by

I have seen many posts on Stack Overflow and on Google but none of them actually helped

Here is the situation, These are my column values:

```
ICT_Member_2014_06_02
ICT_Member_2015_05_05
Creative_Member_1992_09_01
Zealous_Ok_2015_12_22
```

So I want that my result should appear on the based of alphabet and then date (number),
It should be sorted first on alphabet ascending and then on the date.

Any solution for this ?

Thanks

Comment: The original questioner wants descending date order.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY ICT_Member_2014_06_02 DESC, Zealous_Ok_2015_12_22 DESC;
```

Comment: Oh, in that case the query would be: SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY key1 DESC, key2 DESC;

Comment: what is key1 and key2 here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

MySQL: sort by length first and then the column value

```
SELECT col_name
       FROM sorting_test
       ORDER BY LENGTH(col_name), col_name
```

Comment: that didnt work, this will only work if we have common string in all column values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY col_value, 
         DATE(RIGHT(col_value,10)) DESC
```

The first item in ORDER BY will deal with your prefixes.

The second item -- `DATE(RIGHT(col_value,10)` -- will pull out the last ten characters of your values -- the dates. It will then try to handle them as DATE values, and sort them in order. If the date conversion fails (because some of your values don't have the date) those will come first in the ordering.

Comment: ICT_Member - 2012-06-07 appears before the ICT Member - 2012-10-25 which is not correct

Comment: Sorry, I left out a parenthesis.  Fixed. But please explain why `ICT_Member - 2012-06-07` should not come before `ICT_Member - 2012-10-25`. It looks to me like it should.

Comment: I am doing descending on the basis of date, so I am doing DATE(RIGHT(col_value,10)) DESC , that means first it should sort it ascending and then descending on the basis of DATE(RIGHT(col_value,10))

Comment: Your question didn't ask for descending date order. But still it's trivial to handle. Just put DESC after the second sort term.

Comment: please see my last comment, I am using DESC after m second term